# SWT StyledCellLabelProvider crashes Table look and selection

Tags: java, swt, jface

I'm having problem with the way my Table looks, after I use StyledCellLabelProvider.

Here's fast snippets code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.jface.action.CoolBarManager;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.StatusLineManager;
import org.eclipse.jface.layout.TableColumnLayout;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ColumnWeightData;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredContentProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ITableLabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.LabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StyledCellLabelProvider;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StyledString;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.TableViewerColumn;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ViewerCell;
import org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyleRange;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;

public class SwtIssueWithTableSelectionAndBorders extends ApplicationWindow {

    private Table table;
    private TableViewer tableViewer;
    /**
     * Create the application window,
     */
    public SwtIssueWithTableSelectionAndBorders() {
        super(null);
        addCoolBar(SWT.FLAT);
        addMenuBar();
        addStatusLine();
    }

    /**
     * Create contents of the application window.
     * @param parent
     */
    @Override
    protected Control createContents(Composite parent) {
        Composite container = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
        container.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

        Composite composite = new Composite(container, SWT.NONE);
        composite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));

        TableColumnLayout layout = new TableColumnLayout();
        composite.setLayout(layout);

        tableViewer = new TableViewer(composite, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
        table = tableViewer.getTable();
        table.setHeaderVisible(true);
        table.setLinesVisible(false);

        TableViewerColumn tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
        TableColumn tableColumn = tableViewerColumn.getColumn();
        layout.setColumnData(tableColumn, new ColumnWeightData(2, ColumnWeightData.MINIMUM_WIDTH, true));
        tableColumn.setText("Test1");

        tableViewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
        tableColumn = tableViewerColumn.getColumn();
        layout.setColumnData(tableColumn, new ColumnWeightData(2, ColumnWeightData.MINIMUM_WIDTH, true));
        tableColumn.setText("Test2");

        tableViewer.setLabelProvider(new SampleLabelProvider());
        tableViewer.setContentProvider(new ContentProvider());

        StyledCellLabelProvider cellLabelProvider = new StyledCellLabelProvider() {
            @Override
            public void update(ViewerCell cell)
            {
                StyledString text = new StyledString();
                StyleRange myStyledRange = new StyleRange(0, "test".length(), Display.getDefault().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK), null);
                myStyledRange.underline = true;
                text.append("test", StyledString.DECORATIONS_STYLER);
                cell.setText(text.toString());

                StyleRange[] range = { myStyledRange };
                cell.setStyleRanges(range);
                super.update(cell);
            }
        };

        //tableViewerColumn.setLabelProvider(cellLabelProvider);

        initModel();
        initListener();
        return container;
    }

    private void initListener() {
        table.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener() {

            @Override
            public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                table.setEnabled(false);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initModel() {
        List<SampleModel> sampleModelElements = new ArrayList<SampleModel>();
        sampleModelElements.add(new SampleModel("test1_1", "test1_2"));
        sampleModelElements.add(new SampleModel("test2_1", "test2_2"));
        sampleModelElements.add(new SampleModel("test3_1", "test3_2"));
        tableViewer.setInput(sampleModelElements);
    }

    @Override
    protected MenuManager createMenuManager() {
        return new MenuManager("menu");
    }

    @Override
    protected CoolBarManager createCoolBarManager(int style) {
        return new CoolBarManager(style);
    }

    @Override
    protected StatusLineManager createStatusLineManager() {
        return new StatusLineManager();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            SwtIssueWithTableSelectionAndBorders window = new SwtIssueWithTableSelectionAndBorders();
            window.setBlockOnOpen(true);
            window.open();
            Display.getCurrent().dispose();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureShell(Shell newShell) {
        super.configureShell(newShell);
        newShell.setText("TableApp");
    }

    @Override
    protected Point getInitialSize() {
        return new Point(400,300);
    }

    private class SampleLabelProvider extends LabelProvider implements ITableLabelProvider {
        public Image getColumnImage(Object element, int columnIndex) {
            return null;
        }
        public String getColumnText(Object element, int columnIndex) {
            SampleModel sampleModel = (SampleModel) element;
            String result = "";
            switch(columnIndex){
                case 0:
                    result = sampleModel.getTest1();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    result = sampleModel.getTest2();
                    break;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    private class ContentProvider implements IStructuredContentProvider {
        public Object[] getElements(Object inputElement) {
            List<SampleModel> sampleModelElements = (List<SampleModel>)inputElement;
            return sampleModelElements.toArray();
        }
        public void dispose() {
        }
        public void inputChanged(Viewer viewer, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
        }
    }

    private class SampleModel {
        private String test1;
        private String test2;

        public SampleModel(String test1, String test2) {
            super();
            this.test1 = test1;
            this.test2 = test2;
        }

        public String getTest1() {
            return test1;
        }

        public String getTest2() {
            return test2;
        }
   }
}
```

When I run this code everything works as expected.
Table has separator between columns (not between rows because of the table.setLinesVisible(false)):
[image]

And when I click on a row I've got visible disabled selection:
[image]

Problem occurs when I uncomment line:

tableViewerColumn.setLabelProvider(cellLabelProvider);

Than I have no separator between columns:

[image]

And if I press mouse button on one row, than there is no selection in disabled table:

[image]

Is there a way to somehow bring selection back to table when it's disabled and it uses StyledCellLabelProvider?

Comment: If you are going to use a column label provider you should have one for each column and not use the table label provider. Behavior of a disabled table is going to be very platform dependent, on my Mac a disabled table does not respond in any way.

Comment: When I remove line:

    tableViewer.setLabelProvider(new SampleLabelProvider());
And I set label provider for first column also, than it still behaves the same way when I set table to be disabled.

Comment: At a guess this is because the `StyledCellLabelProvider` does a lot more of the table drawing itself rather than delegating to the platform dependent code. Since I don't think there is any defined behavior for selection in a disabled control the code is free to do nothing. As I said on a Mac selection does not work at all in a disabled table regardless of which label provider is used.

Comment: Agree with Greg's findings. It all depends on platform you have. If the platform returns callback on disabled control and passes event info then you should be able to handle it. Else you can't override behavior of native widgets.